# ¿Cómo puedo modificar el ID de paquete en Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift, xcode

Cometí el error de no agregar el "com." a mi bundle ID de mi app en xcode, firebase no me permite cambiarlo, mi pregunta es si es recomendable: eliminar la app IOS y volverla agregar, ya que no puedo eliminar el proyecto por que esta la app de android.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad, uno puede conservar el proyecto existente, al tiempo que solo agrega una nueva aplicación con el paquete actualizado. La aplicación anterior se puede eliminar en el proyecto.

ACTUALIZACIÓN:

una mejor manera sería agregar una nueva aplicación al proyecto y simplemente eliminar la aplicación anterior. La nueva aplicación tendrá su nombre de paquete actualizado. A continuación, descargue google-services.json y reemplácelo con el archivo anterior. Este método sería más seguro, en caso de que su proyecto de Firebase ya tenga integraciones diferentes y eliminarlo no es realmente una opción.

[la fuente mas cercana a tu problema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40641865/i-have-changed-the-package-name-of-my-app-but-on-firebase-it-is-still-the-previ)